# ThreeJS: selective bloom

Tags: three.js

I use EffectComposer and BloomPass to make my scene overbright. However, I need to disable it for whole scene and use for selected objects only. I came up with something like that:

- Render scene without selected objects.
- Save colorbuffer
- Clear color buffer, but not depth buffer
- Render selected objects only.
- Do bloom pass
- Blend saved colorbuffer over with some kinky mode

Is it worth to twist my so called "engine" this way, or there is some easier way?

Comment: I was wondering if you eventually managed to solve this?

Comment: I would be interested in that as well...